# ISDN dial up connection with python

Tags: python, dial-up, isdn

I have a requirement to create a Python application that accepts dial up connections over ISDN from client software and relays messages from this connection to a website application running on a LAMP webserver.

Do we have some modules or support for this kind of implementation in python?

Please suggest.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You should have system hardware and software that handles establishing ISDN links, that's not something you should be trying to reimplement yourself.

You need to consult the documentation for that hardware and software, and the documentation for the client software, to determine how that connection can be made available to your application, and what communications protocol the client will be using over the ISDN link.

(If you're really lucky, the client actually uses PPP to establish a TCP/IP connection.)

Comment: I don't have much knowledge about the network protocols or socket programming but I have read somewhere that a socket connection created through the python application can accept all kinds of data.

Comment: @anand: It certainly can, and if you're interested in sockets, you should read the documentation for Python's socket module and perhaps even Beej's Guide to Network Programming (which uses C for its examples, but is pretty broadly useful for anyone using a typical socket library in any language). But that doesn't help you by itself. You have a rather specialized need involving ISDN, and you need to consult the documentation for your equipment to know how to proceed. Python's socket capabilities may or may not be of any use to you here.

Comment: hmm, well I do not have such a documentation for the equipment so I am looking for an alternative. Thanks for your reply Nicholas.